# Remove text before a number in Excel

Tags: excel

I have to remove some text either before or after a number in Excel and sometimes both. i.e.

`Dr Smith Surgery 154 which ever road`

I need to split this up into `Dr Smith Surgery 154`  and `which ever road`.

Now some records only have `154 which ever road`.

Can anyone advise? I have a few thousands of records to adjust and the thought of doing this manually just makes me want to cry.

Comment: So if the text is in A1, you need the two resulting strings to appear e.g. in cell B1 and C1?

Comment: Will there only ever be one occurrence of a number in the string?

Comment: Will try above first as this is similar though not sure if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you wish to parse and run this small macro:

```
Sub Parser()
    Dim s1 As String, r As Range, _
        L As Long, i As Long
    For Each r In Selection
    s1 = r.Text
    L = Len(s1)
    For i = L To 1 Step -1
        If IsNumeric(Mid(s1, i, 1)) Then
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Left(s1, i)
            r.Offset(0, 2).Value = Mid(s1, i + 1)
            GoTo dun
        End If
    Next i
dun:
    Next r
End Sub
```

Everything to the right of the last digit will be put in column **C**
Everything else will be put in column **B**

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your value is in A1.
Suppose you create a helper column in B1.
Column C1 is your formula for the left side.
Column D1 is your formula for the right side.

In B1, replace all the numbers with a character your text is guaranteed not to contain, and then get the location of the first instance of that character. Here I chose pipe ("|"). Formula for B1:

```
=SEARCH("|",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, 1, "|"), 2, "|"), 3, "|"), 4, "|"), 5, "|"), 6, "|"), 7, "|"), 8, "|"), 9, "|"), 0, "|"))
```

Formula for C1:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,B1- 1), A1)
```

Formula for D1:

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,B1, LEN( A1)-B1+1), "")
```

Should you elect not to use a helper column, you can create two giant formulas of doom with the following:

Formula for left side:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("|",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, 1, "|"), 2, "|"), 3, "|"), 4, "|"), 5, "|"), 6, "|"), 7, "|"), 8, "|"), 9, "|"), 0, "|"))- 1), A1)
```

Formula for right side:

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("|",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, 1, "|"), 2, "|"), 3, "|"), 4, "|"), 5, "|"), 6, "|"), 7, "|"), 8, "|"), 9, "|"), 0, "|")), LEN( A1)-SEARCH("|",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, 1, "|"), 2, "|"), 3, "|"), 4, "|"), 5, "|"), 6, "|"), 7, "|"), 8, "|"), 9, "|"), 0, "|"))+1), "")
```

Comment: This is almost the same solution as in linked answer. You can create Name to simplify giant formulas.